# MySQL Error 1442: Can't Update Table, but Table isn't being referenced?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm writing a procedure to loop through various insect collectors, some of which are split by commas, eg. "V. Shirey, L. Smith" from which I need to create a new row for each individual collector. My procedure looks like this:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS agent_reclamation;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE agent_reclamation (IN VerbatimName VARCHAR(170)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE verbatimNameHandler varchar(170);
DECLARE tempAgentName varchar(170); 
SET verbatimNameHandler = VerbatimName;
    WHILE LENGTH(verbatimNameHandler) > 0 DO -- while there's more stuff left
        IF LOCATE(',', verbatimNameHandler) > 0 THEN -- and theres a comma to be found
            SET tempAgentName = SUBSTRING(verbatimNameHandler,1,LOCATE(',',verbatimNameHandler) - 1); -- set the temp variable to everything from the first character to the first comma
        ELSE
            SET tempAgentName = verbatimNameHandler; -- set the name if there are no commas
            SET verbatimNameHandler = ''; -- won't accept procedure without update --
        END IF;
            INSERT INTO agentReclamation SET tempAgentName = tempAgentName;
        /* INSERT INTO agentReclamation(tempAgentName) VALUES (tempAgentName); */ -- insert the new names into the agentReclamation table
        SET verbatimNameHandler = REPLACE(verbatimNameHandler, tempAgentName + ',', ''); -- won't accept procedure without update --
    END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;

SELECT agent_reclamation(VerbatimName) FROM tempAgent WHERE VerbatimName LIKE 
'%,%';
```

I am getting Error 1442 stating, Can't update table 'tempAgent' in stored function/trigger because it is used in the statement that invoked this stored function/trigger. I can't see where I have positioned myself to update 'tempAgent' anywhere withing the procedure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm just getting the hang of writing my own procedures currently. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't there a trigger on table `agentReclamation`, that does something with table `tempAgent` ?

Comment: @j.kaspar it looks like his only reference to the `tempAgent` table is outside the stored proc definition anyway. Vaughn, can you run a similar insert outside of the stored procedure?

Comment: @Uueerdo, I ran the insert fine outside of the procedure - I actually just solved the issue. I ended up needing 2 procedures: One in which I define a cursor and loop through each row while calling the agent_reclamation procedure and the agent_reclamation procedure itself. One of the major offenders here was trying to call a procedure in the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done is create two procedures, one in which there is iteration through each row with a procedure call to the original procedure. See below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS agent_reclamation;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procIteration;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE procIteration ()
BEGIN
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE verbatimNameHandler varchar(170);
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT VerbatimName FROM tempAgent WHERE VerbatimName LIKE '%,%';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

OPEN cur;

testLoop: LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO verbatimNameHandler;
    IF done THEN 
        LEAVE testLoop;
    END IF;
    CALL agent_reclamation(verbatimNameHandler);
END LOOP testLoop;

CLOSE cur;
END //

CREATE PROCEDURE agent_reclamation (IN VerbatimName VARCHAR(170)) 
BEGIN
DECLARE verbatimNameHandler varchar(170);
DECLARE tempAgentName varchar(170); 
SET verbatimNameHandler = VerbatimName;
    WHILE LENGTH(verbatimNameHandler) > 0 DO -- while there's more stuff left
        IF LOCATE(',', verbatimNameHandler) > 0 THEN -- and theres a comma to be found
            SET tempAgentName = SUBSTRING(verbatimNameHandler,1,LOCATE(',',verbatimNameHandler) - 1); -- set the temp variable to everything from the first character to the first comma
        ELSE
            SET tempAgentName = verbatimNameHandler; -- set the name if there are no commas
            SET verbatimNameHandler = ''; -- won't accept procedure without update --
        END IF;
        -- INSERT INTO agentReclamation SET tempAgentName = tempAgentName;
        INSERT INTO agentReclamation(tempAgentName) VALUES (tempAgentName);  -- insert the new names into the agentReclamation table
        SET verbatimNameHandler = REPLACE(verbatimNameHandler, CONCAT(tempAgentName, ','), ''); -- won't accept procedure without update --
    END WHILE;
END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL procIteration();
```

This produces the intended results.